# Figures in Latex template for JETP Letters on Overleaf

Tags: floats, templates

I am trying to insert a figure in the LaTeX template of JETP Letters journal. The template is here (`example.tex`):
http://www.jetpletters.ac.ru/en/info.shtml

In the template there is no figure, so I tried with and without using the `graphicx` package with the following code with no success.

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{Fig1.eps}
\end{figure}
```

Does not work for any eps or pdf figure.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem. Just added a

```
 \usepackage{color}
```

which resolved undocumented feature of this template.